# R, superimposing a barplot as a scale on a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working in RStudio and using ggplot2. I want to create a bar plot that will effectively act as a scale for meters/second. I then want to create a ggplot graph with this bar plot superimposed and slightly transparent on the graph. So, I will have something like this:

```
   barplot(DF1,space=20,axes=FALSE,las=2,col=1,xlab="meters/second")
```

Which creates this:
[image: Barplot]

ggplot is:

```
ggplot(DF2, aes(x=Time, y=N1_ave)) + geom_line() + ylim(-1,1) + ggtitle("0.07 MA Average")
```

which creates:

[image: ggplot]

What I want after combining them is something like this:

[image: combined]

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Do you want simply to overlay one plot on top of another or draw the grid using ggplot? Anyway, adding the `dput(DF)` would definitely help.

Comment: If it is possible just to overlay one plot on the other (to make the third image), that would be perfect.

Comment: I haven't met an example of such overlay and I don't think this is easy. Drawing the grid with ggplot seems easy enough though, but only if x scales are aligned somehow.

Comment: I see, it is probably not possible to make the barplot have the same x scale (they are two separate measures), so I guess there is no way to do this. I also couldn't find any previous attempts at something similar.

Comment: I noticed that you can add a graph ontop of another graph even if they don't have the same values by simply adding "+ geom_bar()" and enter the values like you normally would and simply change the opacity of the bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your data, but based on your description, how about this: We'll create a single `ggplot`, but we'll use one data frame to plot `N1_ave` using `geom_line` and another to create the vertical lines using `geom_segment`. This way, `ggplot` takes care of all the scaling and we don't have to worry about matching scales between two different plots.

The key is that you have to set the x-values in `barVals` so that the vertical lines are plotted in the correct locations on the graph. For this example, I've just made them up because I don't know what the actual values are supposed to be.

Here's an example with fake data:

```
# This is the data series
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(x=seq(0,0.15,length.out=200), y=rnorm(200,0,0.2))

# These are the meters/second labels for the vertical lines
labels=c(0.27,0.29,0.31,0.33,0.36,0.4,0.44,0.5,
         0.57,0.67,0.8,1,1.34,2.01,4.02,Inf)

# These are the x-values for where the vertical lines will be plotted 
# (plus the labels created above)
barVals = data.frame(x=seq(0.005,0.145,length.out=length(labels)),
                     labels=labels)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_segment(data=barVals, aes(x=x, xend=x), y=-0.8, yend=0.8, colour="grey70") +
  geom_text(data=barVals, aes(label=labels), y=-0.85, size=4, colour="grey50") +
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1)) +
  labs(x="Time", y="N1_ave") +
  annotate(geom="text", x=0.075, y=-0.95, label="meters/second", colour="grey50")
```

[image]